# c# delete main executable and all dependency Dlls during execution

Tags: c#, window

I want to delete the main executable plus all dependency dlls after start of a c# executable. I can delete the files (via IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION from kernelmode) but the application crashes likely due to paged out memory and can not fetch it from disk:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
```

I am currently looking at VirtualLock to lock all pages. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: The reason you mention as likely is not likely at all.  When there is paging going on, the backing file is locked, so depending on the version of your windows, you either cannot delete it, or it appears to be deleted, but in fact it is not deleted until it gets unlocked.  Your problem is something else.  You have not told us exactly how it crashes.  Could it be that it crashes ***precisely because the call to delete itself fails, because it is locked?***

Comment: I updated my question.